# TV series with alien larvae that infect humans through their eyes and turn them into blood drinkers

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, alien-invasion

What sci fi series featured on Foxtel about a plane landing where there aren't any live humans inside?

Turns out there are some blood-sucking type of aliens on board (in the form of small worm-like larvae) which crawl inside the host through the eyes, turning them into blood-sucking humans, which then attack others with an extra-long pipe-like projecting mouth?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve your question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit]ing in any additional details you remember.  For example, approximately when did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: Thank you for the reply - that is exactly the series I was referring to- what a awesome site this is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Strain* (2014)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strain_(TV_series)):

> The show centers around Dr. Ephraim Goodweather, the head of the CDC's New York-based Canary Project, who is called upon to **investigate an airplane landing wherein everyone aboard is dead.** What his team discovers is a **viral outbreak that has similarities to an ancient strain of vampirism.** The virus begins to spread and Goodweather works with his team and a group of the city's residents to wage a war to save humanity.

The poster for season 1 has a long "tongue". See also this [gross, NSFW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzhSm.jpg) picture of the larva going inside an eye.

[image: weird long tongue]

---

Found with the Google query `tv series blood sucking larvae through eyes`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. That is the series I was searching for- thanks to you I can now go find the episodes I wish to revisit 

Comment: @Mary you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! :)

Comment: I never saw the tv series, but highly recommend the books.